# Dynamic columns inbiquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am using five rows called bucket-a, bucket-b etc like below to create an array like below. Is there a way to do this for dynamic number of columns ?

```
with matrix as (
---element x 

 select "element-x" as element, "bucketa" bucket , 1 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-x" as element, "bucketb" bucket , 1 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-x" as element, "bucketc" bucket , 1 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-x" as element, "bucketd" bucket , 0 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-x" as element, "buckete" bucket , 0 eligibilty 

union all
---element y 

 select "element-y" as element, "bucketa" bucket , 0 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-y" as element, "bucketb" bucket , 0 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-y" as element, "bucketc" bucket , 1 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-y" as element, "bucketd" bucket , 0 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-y" as element, "buckete" bucket , 0 eligibilty 
union all
---element z

 select "element-z" as element, "bucketa" bucket , 1 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-z" as element, "bucketb" bucket , 0 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-z" as element, "bucketc" bucket , 1 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-z" as element, "bucketd" bucket , 0 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-z" as element, "buckete" bucket , 0 eligibilty 
union all
---element p

 select "element-p" as element, "bucketa" bucket , 0 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-p" as element, "bucketb" bucket , 0 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-p" as element, "bucketc" bucket , 1 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-p" as element, "bucketd" bucket , 0 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-p" as element, "buckete" bucket , 0 eligibilty 
union all
---element q

 select "element-q" as element, "bucketa" bucket , 1 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-q" as element, "bucketb" bucket , 0 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-q" as element, "bucketc" bucket , 0 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-q" as element, "bucketd" bucket , 0 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-q" as element, "buckete" bucket , 0 eligibilty 

union all
---element r

 select "element-r" as element, "bucketa" bucket , 0 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-r" as element, "bucketb" bucket , 1 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-r" as element, "bucketc" bucket , 0 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-r" as element, "bucketd" bucket , 1 eligibilty 
 union all 
 select "element-r" as element, "buckete" bucket , 0 eligibilty 



) 

, buckets_elements as ( 
  select array[struct(a), struct(b), struct(c), struct(d), struct(e)] buckets
  from (
    select 
      array_agg(if(bucket = 'bucketa' and eligibilty = 1, element, null) ignore nulls) a,
      array_agg(if(bucket = 'bucketb' and eligibilty = 1, element, null) ignore nulls) b,
      array_agg(if(bucket = 'bucketc' and eligibilty = 1, element, null) ignore nulls) c,
      array_agg(if(bucket = 'bucketd' and eligibilty = 1, element, null) ignore nulls) d,
      array_agg(if(bucket = 'buckete' and eligibilty = 1, element, null) ignore nulls) e
    from matrix
  )
```

)

MAtrix is my dataset, there is a column in there called bucket. The values in the column should be dynamically used in the second temp table buckets_elements instead of explicitly using the bucket values.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? Can you describe what should create the column?

Comment: I have edited the question, added the data set and some descriptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is hard to answer this particular question without having whole context available  - so I am using your previous question as a such - [Fewest buckets to fit in the elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66501246/fewest-buckets-to-fit-in-the-elements). Also to make it easier - I had to refactor initial solution that is based on use of CTEs - to split all into separate temp tables. So `buckets_elements` becomes one of such table and can be easily dynamically created

So, finally, consider below to make your code fully dynamic

```
create temp table columns_names as 
  select array_agg(bucket order by bucket) cols
  from (select distinct bucket from matrix)
;

execute immediate (
select '''
create temp table buckets_elements as  
  select array[''' || string_agg('''struct(col''' || offset || ''')''') || '''] buckets
  from (
    select ''' || string_agg('''
      array_agg(if(bucket = "''' || col || '''" and eligibilty = 1, element, null) ignore nulls) col''' || offset , ', ') || '''      
    from matrix
  );
'''
from columns_names, unnest(cols) col with offset
);

create temp table columns_index as 
  select generate_array(0, array_length(cols) - 1) as arr  
  from columns_names
;

create temp table buckets_combinations as 
  select  
    (select array_agg(
      case when n & (1<<pos) <> 0 then arr[offset(pos)] end 
      ignore nulls)
     from unnest(generate_array(0, array_length(arr) - 1)) pos
    ) as combo
  from columns_index cross join 
  unnest(generate_array(1, cast(power(2, array_length(arr)) - 1 as int64))) n
;

create temp table temp1 as 
    select any_value(c).combo, array_agg(buckets[offset(i)]) val
    from buckets_combinations c, unnest(combo) i, buckets_elements b
    group by format('%t', c)
;    

create temp table temp2 as 
  select combo, 
    rank() over(order by (select count(distinct  el) from unnest(val) v, unnest(v.col0) el) desc, array_length(combo)) as rnk
  from temp1
;

select array_agg(cols[offset(i)]) winners
from temp2,columns_names, unnest(combo) i
where rnk = 1
group by format('%t', combo)
```

As you can see  - there is no any reference in code to neither buckets names nor their counts - so code is fully dynamic

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: is there a way to get the element as well, in the output? otherwise this works perfectly so I am accepting the solution

Comment: isn't this as simple as `select distinct element from matrix where eligibilty = 1` ?

Comment: Your answer seemed extremely efficient so wanted to see if I can just get it as a part of it, than writing another query. Nevermind, this is huge help already!! Appreciate it!

Comment: I gave you pretty good hint in my last comment on how to make it  - so you should really try to do something by yourself. so please TRY!!!. if still problem  - post new question - this one is fully answered :o)